# forward pipe tuple to a method with optional params

Tags: f#, optional-parameters

I got piece of code like this:

```
type x() =
    member x.f(number:int, ?text:string) =
        "doesn't matter"

let instance = new x()
let result = instance.f(1, "s")
```

This works fine, but as I was doing some refactoring I've found, that the following won't even compile.

```
let param = (1,"s")
let result2 = param |> instance.f
```

The error message is `Type constraint mismatch. The type      int * string     is not compatible with type     int     The type 'int * string' is not compatible with the type 'int'`

If the `f()` method has both parameters non optional, second example works fine.

In my real code, this tuple is larger (5 values) and is calculated by a separate function. How can I deal with this?

(I uploaded this example in LinqPad into http://share.linqpad.net/cu92w2.linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `instance.f` is not really a first-class F# syntactic function. It's rather a standard .NET method invocation so it doesn't behave exactly the same way due to some design decisions related to interoperability. These differences become evident in presence of features unique to methods (but not to functions) such as overloads and as in this case optional arguments.

If you wrap it into a function it will work as you expect:

```
let callf (a, b) = instance.f (a, b)
let param = (1,"s")
let result2 = param |> callf
```

Of course now the function has no optional argument, the optional argument resolution was made at the function definition.